# Expression tree is too large (Maximum depth 1000) sqlite windows

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I am new to SQLITE and in my project, i need to select the data from the .db file but unfortunately, the data which I am selecting is too big. The query is

```
SELECT distinct * FROM RunTime WHERE Local_Machine = 'GTS-VINAY'  and ((Variable like '[MCUL_ErrorMessage@2]%') or (Variable like '[MCUL_UniqueID@1]%')[....])
```

Here an exception was thrown Expression tree is too large (Maximum depth 1000) I googled a lot and found that people are saying to set limit of SQLITE_LIMIT_EXPR_DEPTH with reference to link http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=31731#p109439
But here the question is how can I implement the same in C# WinForms.

Note: I am trying to add reference of sqlite3 in by project but vs 2013 is not allowing to add the same.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the patterns into a temporary table, and let the database iterate over it:

```sql
SELECT RunTime.*
FROM RunTime
JOIN TempTable ON RunTime.Variable LIKE TempTable.Variable
WHERE Local_Machine = 'GTS-VINAY';
```